# Avro immutable generated class in java

Tags: java, avro

Does Avro support generating an immutable class from schema in Java?

Been reading online a bit and it doesn't seem like its supported but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can achieve that by adding:

```
<configuration>
     <createSetters>false</createSetters>
     <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
</configuration>
```

To the avro maven plugin.

```
avro {
    createSetters = false
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
}
```

Or the above in `build.gradle` if you are using gradle